# Tensor product of reducible representations of SU(2)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tensor-products

I have a reducible SU(2) representation $D^{(\alpha)}$, which can be decomposed as, say $D^{(\alpha)} = D^{(m)}\oplus D^{(n)}$ where the representations on the right-hand side are irreducible. I know that there is a general formula for the decomposition of the tensor product of irreducible representations ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_representations#The_SU(2)_case)).

Now, if I want to find the decomposition of the tensor product of the reducible representation, i.e., $D^{(\alpha)} \otimes D^{(\alpha)}$, is it possible to write a general formula for the decomposition using the results of the Wikipedia entry and the decomposition of $D^{(\alpha)}$?

Comment: Tensor product distributes over direct sum.